# React Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': parameter 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I'm getting a strange error - trying to trigger the next and prev events on scroll within react for [react-slick](http://neostack.com/opensource/react-slick) slider.

Error:

TypeError: Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': parameter 1 ('options') is not an object.

```
  29 | 
  30 | componentWillMount(){
  31 |     window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
> 32 |         this.scroll(e.wheelDelta);
  33 |     })
  34 | }
  35 |
```

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.scroll = this.scroll.bind(this);
    }

    scroll(y){
        y > 0 ? (
           this.slider.slickNext()
        ) : (
           this.slider.slickPrev()
        )
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
            this.scroll(e.wheelDelta);
        })
    }

<Slider {...settings} ref={slider => this.slider = slider}>
                    {sliderItems}
                </Slider>
```

Comment: `console.log(this); this.scroll(e.wheelDelta);`

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure where you'd like to see this logged?

Comment: It is for you, what do you see for `this`, is it what you expect? Basic debugging.

Comment: @Filth, sorry I've confused `wheelDeltaX` with `wheelDelta` I've deleted my answer, but there is this code that might be helpful at the end of this article : [Listening to wheell event across browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel)

Comment: Still in my opinion, I stay away from those new events until they are stable and have widespread support, if you take this opinion you might consider move on to scroll for example.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve and works here? https://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/mMLQQb